# How to access user lists for other organisations using the Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure, rest, graph, multi-tenant

I am looking after multiple organisations Office 365 subscriptions and would like to be able to easily access a list of all users at all organisations.

I understand that this isn't straightforward and I know I can create an Azure Application at each organisation but is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, [List Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is used to get the users of the current authorized organization. I'm afraid there is no direct method to access a list of all users at all organizations.

Comment: So I guess this means using something like the Microsoft Partner API?